# Make shell script executable upon extraction from zip

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-scripting, github, teamcity

I have a shell file that is pulled from github and built into a zip using TeamCity.

It is typically edited and put into github from a Windows machine.

I need this shell script to be executable upon unzipping. How do I do this? Currently I have to do chmod +x blah.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest and easiest solution would probably be to use a shell script that addresses your permissions after running the unzip.

Comment: Yeah - I guess I was hoping for a way to avoid this. But the unzip is already being run via shell script, so I will just do this! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /bin/bash
#First argument ($1) would be the name of the file to be unzipped
#Second argument ($2) would be where to unzip the files to (absolute path)
unzip $1 -d $2
find $2 -name *.sh -print0 | xargs -0 chmod +x
```

This would work as long as the files you were wanting to make as executable were always going to be *.sh.  Otherwise could always add a third argument ($3) and substitute it for the *.sh but then you would always have to input the name of the file to be made executable for every archive.

Comment: That would make all the files from the zip u+x though, would it not?  Including adding traverse permissions to all directories and execute to non-executable files?

Comment: Very true.  The script would go in /usr/bin.  Still a kludge but best way I could think of to address the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should create the archive with a Unix zip to preserve the Unix attributes.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not zipping it, TeamCity is.

Answer (score 0):

What shell are you using?  I know in bash you can define your own commands (via alias), for example once i made a custom command i called cdsee and it took a single parameter (a directory) and cd'd to it, then ls -lah immediately.  made it very easy to do my work, as i immediately saw the contents of said folder.

It should, likewise, be possible, and even easy, to make a command that would run the unzip command, and then immediately chmod +x.

Unfortunately, how to pull arguments is escaping me at the moment.  But the simplest answer would be to use a linux machine for the originating zip-job, or making your custom command/alias execute the chmod automatically.

Comment: Having an alias with its own semantic arguments is kind of a kludge.  It would very nearly be better to write a small script and place it in /usr/bin or something.

Comment: it works, and is simple to implement.  what's the problem with that?
also, i don't entirely know what you're talking about with a small script in usr/bin.  an alias is just the solution i know of that would work.